# HTML5 canvas, scale image after drawing it

Tags: image, html, canvas, scale

I'm trying to scale an image that has already been draw into canvas.
This is the code:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('splash-container');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
var imageObj = new Image();

imageObj.onload = function() {
  // draw image at its original size
  context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
};
imageObj.src = 'images/mine.jpeg';

// Now let's scale the image.
// something like...
imageObj.scale(0.3, 0.3);
```

How should I do?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You're thinking about it wrong.  Once you've drawn the image onto the `canvas` it has no relationship to the `imageObj` object.  Nothing you do to `imageObj` will affect what's already drawn.  If you want to scale the image, do in the [`drawImage` function](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/Canvas_tutorial/Using_images):

```
drawImage(imgObj, 0, 0, imgObj.width * 0.3, imgObj.height * 0.3)
```

If you want to animate the scaling or are looking to achieve some other effect which requires you to draw the image at full size initially you'll have to first [clear it](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/html5-canvas/clearrect.html) before drawing the scaled down image.

Comment: I found a solution using Kinetic library and transitionTo() method

Answer (score 6):

What robertc says is correct, but if you really wanted to scale an image on a canvas *after* drawing it for some reason, you could just scale the whole canvas using the CSS width/height properties and that would scale the image without having to redraw it.

Comment: Well, I cannot scale the entire canvas because there're other objects in it, that I don't want to scale. I wanna make appear a logo on a splash screen, that should rotate and scale itself to its original size.